# magento 2 ; How do I create and call a block in a phtml without using a layout xml

Tags: magento2

In magento 1 I could create a block/ attach a phtml to it and then call it as follows ;

```
<?php print $this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("catalog/product_view")
                 ->setTemplate("catalog/product/view/addto.phtml")
                 ->toHtml(); ?>
```

is it possible in magento 2 to create a block and then attach a phtml file without using a layout.xml.

the reason for asking is that i dont want to attach the layout to a specific page/default but wish  to call it in whatever location I want

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure you can do that with 
        **\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,**

```
$layout->createBlock(ClassName)->setTemplate('template_file')->toHtml();
```

In the template, you can use

```
echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock(ClassName)->setTemplate('template_file')->toHtml();
```

Comment: if i call this within my phtml page, where would the $layout variable come from?

Comment: You can using $block->getLayout().